I can't knit in Rstudio
I'm doing a very basic homework for beginners in Rstudio in a windows computer. I am done so I want to Knit it and it doesn't let me.

I asked Chatgpt how to fix it but it still doesn't let me Knit to anything and I have to turn in my assignment. I would appreciate very much if someone helped me. I don't know how to fix "execution halted".
I was trying to knit the document to pdf or HTLM by pressing knit

Please provide an example of your code that is leading you to the error.

how would we know what the issue is if you don't share your code? Please provide the code that is causing the error
